# How do I prevent an infinite loop in the useEffect function in React caused by a custom hook's function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question about React.

In the following code, `mutateAsync` in `useEffect` is called infinitely due to the function in the custom hook. Can you tell me why?

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
  const func = () => {
      ...doSomething
    }

  return {
    func,
  };
};

export default useCustomHook;
```

```
const Component = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const customHook = useCustomHook();

  const { mutateAsync } = useMutation();

  const handleFunc = useCallback(async () => {
    if ( !router.isReady ) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      await mutateAsync();

      customHook.func();
    } catch (error) {
    }
  }, [
    mutateAsync,
    router.isReady,
    customHook,
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleFunc();
  }, [handleFunc]);

  return <></>;
};

export default Component;
```

Comment: Where's `useMutation` coming from? If it's `useSWR` or `react-query` then it can take on `onSuccess` and/or `onError` callbacks, which is probably the right place to put your `customHook.func` (likewise you probably want to use `mutate` instead of `mutateAsync`, but that's somewhat of an aside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`customHook` from `useCustomHook()` call returns a new object, so its reference changes every render. Since its also a dependency of `useCallback` function `handleFunc`, so the reference of `handleFunc` also changes every render. Thus `handleFunc` gets called every render in the `useEffect` while the dependency is itself.

Here's what you could do to avoid the infinite loop:

1. Make `useCustomHook` return a `useCallback` function with dependencies of an empty array.

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
  const func = useCallback(() => {
      ...doSomething
  }, []);

  return {
    func,
  };
};

export default useCustomHook;
```

2. Use the callback function `func` as a dependency for `handleFunc` but not the hook object itself (or just omit it):

```js
const Component = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { func } = useCustomHook();

  const { mutateAsync } = useMutation();

  const handleFunc = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!router.isReady) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      await mutateAsync();
      func();
    } catch (error) {
    }
  }, [
    mutateAsync, 
    router.isReady, 
    func
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleFunc();
  }, [handleFunc]);

  return <></>;
};

export default Component;
```